# Excel: Get a particular value by key from a set of rows

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table with purchase orders. Eg:

```
order  | order line | line status   
-----------------------------------
1      | 1          | Received     
1      | 2          | Waiting  
2      | 1          | Received
```

I need to add an automatic column (obtained with a formula) with the status of the order:

```
order  | order line | line status   | order status
-------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1          | Received     | Waiting
1      | 2          | Waiting      | Waiting
2      | 1          | Received     | Received
```

Explanation:

The order **1** has one line **received** and one line **waiting**, so the formula must return **waiting**, which is the status of the whole order. When the line **2** is received, both lines would be in **received** status, so the order status calculated by the formula must be **received**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS in an IF:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"Waiting"),"Waiting","Received")
```

Put in D2 and copy down.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your VERY quick answer! I aml tringy it, but I think it will work!